Lanczos convergence for symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $1,2,\cdots,2,100$
Suppose that $A$ is symmetric with eigenvalues $1,2,\cdots,2,100 \in \mathbb{R}^{100x100}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{100}$ obtained by normalizing a standard normal random vector.
Show that 1 and 100 are among the three Ritz values obtained after three iterations of
the Arnoldi method.
So in a first moment an hint was to show to first show that $\lambda_{max}(H_3)$(where $H_3$ states for the Hessemberg factor of Krylov subspace after $3$ iterations)
is equal to max$\{\rho_{A}(x) : x \in K_3(A, b)\}$, where $\rho_{A}(x)$ is the Rayleigh quotient of $A$.
I showed the hint but I don't know how to proceed. I think is okay to assume that with probability one $100$ is an eigenvalue because after three iteration the convergence of the eigenvalue approximated with a factor $10^{-8}$ I think. How could I proceed?
Any help or reference would be appreciated.

We shall begin by summarizing the salient properties of the Arnoldi algorithm.
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and let $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $S_m = \{1,2,\dotsc,m\}$ and let $\Omega \subseteq S_m$ be given by
$$ \Omega = \{ k \in S_m \: : \: \exists \: \text{polynomial $p$ of degree $k$ s.t. $p(A)b = 0$.} \}$$
We observe that the $m+1$ vectors $$b, Ab, A^2b, \dotsc, A^mb \in \mathbb{R}^m$$ cannot be linearly independent. It follows that $m \in \Omega$. By the well ordering principle, $\Omega$ has a smallest element $n$. This is the grade of $b$ with respect to $A$. We emphasize that if $q$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree $k < n$, then $q(A)b \not = 0$.
Now in exact arithmetic, the Arnoldi algorithm will return a tall orthogonal matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and an upper Hessenberg matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $$AV = VH$$ and the columns of $V$ span the Krylov subspace $K(A,b)$ given by
$$ K(A,b) = \text{span} \{b, Ab, \dots, A^{n-1}b \}.$$
We note that the dimension of $K(A,b)$ is $n$, precisely because $q(A)b$ cannot vanish unless the degree of $q$ is at least $n$. We observe that $K(A,b)$ is the smallest $A$-invariant subspace that contains $b$.
This completes our summary of the properties of the Arnoldi algorithm. We shall now address the specific question. A symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ has three distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$. A vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is given. We can write $$b = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$$ where $$A x_i = \lambda_i x_i.$$ We shall assume that
$$ x_i \not = 0.$$
By the symmetry of $A$, we have that $x_i \perp x_j$ for $i \not = j$. It follows that $p(A)b = 0$ if and only if $p(A)x_i = 0$ for all $i$. We conclude that $$p(A)b = 0$$ where $p$ is the polynomial given by $$p(x) = (x-\lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)(x - \lambda_3).$$ Moreover, $$q(A)b \not = 0$$ if $q$ is any polynomial of degree $1$ and $2$. We conclude that $n=3$.
Let $$W = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{x_1}{\|x_1\|} & \frac{x_2}{\|x_2\|} & \frac{x_3}{\|x_3\|} \end{bmatrix}$$ We observe that the column space $C(W)$ is an $A$-invariant subspace that contain $b$ and has dimension $3$. It follows that $C(W) = C(V)$. We conclude that $H = V^T A V$ is similar to $$W^TAW = \text{diag}\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\}.$$ It follows that the eigenvalues of $H$ and $A$ are identical. This completes the analysis.
EDIT: Why is $C(W) = C(V)$? By definition, we have $C(V) = K(A,b)$ is the smallest $A$ invariant subspace that contains $b$. Since $C(W)$ is an A-invariant subspace that contain $b$, because $$b = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = W \begin{bmatrix} \|x_1\| \\ \|x_2\| \\ \|x_3\| \end{bmatrix} \in C(W)$$ we automatically have that $$C(V) \subseteq C(W).$$ However, since the dimensions of $C(V)$ and $C(W)$ are equal, we cannot have $C(V) \not = C(W)$. In particular, if we assume that there exists $w \in C(W)$ such that $w \not \in C(V)$, then we can show that the four vectors $$\{v_1, v_2, v_3, w\}$$ are linearly independent. Why is that? Here $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ denote the columns of $V$. Suppose that $$s_1 v_1 + s_2 v_2 + s_3 v_3 + s w = 0.$$ for a selection of scalars $s_i$ and $s$. If $s=0$, then $s_i = 0$ by the linear independence of the $v_i$. If $s \not = 0$, then $w = -\frac{1}{s}(s_1 v_1 + s_2 v_2 + s_3 v_3) \in C(V)$ which violates our assumption of $w \not \in C(V)$. It follows that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, w\}$ are linearly independent. We conclude that $C(W)$ has dimension at least $4$. This conflicts with the fact that $W$ has a basis consisting of the 3 vectors $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

$b$ is a linear combination shouldn't be coefficient with $1$ right?
Also I understand the part of $q(A)$ but I don't understand why $C(W) = C(V)$ based on the invariant argument. Could you expand? Thanks

@jacopoburelli Certainly. I have added more words on this matter.

Doesn’t this technically show that if I have $n$ distinct eigenvalues after n steps I have all of them inside $K_n(x_0,A)$?

@jacopoburelli Your generalization is perfectly correct. Naturally, we have to assume that $b$ has a nonzero component in direction of each eigenspace, but this almost certainly satisfied in practice. Note, that we rarely have $n$ much smaller than $m$, but it happens that the spectrum of $A$ is tightly clustered, especially in the context of preconditioned matrices.

And why did you assumed it in “theory”? This is related to my previous question, i.e the linear combination of b, which should have coefficients.

@jacopoburelli Suppose that ${u_i}_{i=1}^m$ is orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ consisting of eigenvectors for $A$. Now consider the set of vectors $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $b^T u_i = 0$ for at least one $i$. This set is a surface with Lebegue measure zero. The probability of picking a member of a particular set is an increasing function of the measure of the set and zero for sets of measure zero. Hence, there is little to worry about. I worry marginally and while I recognize that rounding errors will almost certainly help us, I prefer to state the necessary assumption up front.
